# Qual a importância dos Viriatos para a língua portuguesa?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica, significado-em-contexto

[Viriatos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viriatos) e a língua portuguesa.
Qual a sua importância?

Comment: CIMend, mudei de "veriato" para "viriato", que é a grafia que encontrei nos dicionários, e adicionei um link para o verbete correspondente na Wikipedia, já que creio que nem todos saibam do que se trata (eu mesmo não sabia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os viriatos foram alguns milhares de portugueses lutando por alguns anos na Espanha. Isso provavelmente não teve uma influência muito relevante, comparada a já existente devido à proximidade cultural e geográfica entre os dois países.

Comment: Mas existiu O Viriato, um guerreiro valente que lutou contra os romanos

Comment: @ClMend A a ele que você se refere??

Comment: Os viriatos que fala têm origem neste Viriato ?

Comment: @CIMend o nome sim.